# Generate JSON onModelChange from multiple input text box angular

Tags: javascript, json, angular, ngfor

I have a requirement in which I'm capturing changed values from input text boxes.

The table is designed in such a way that

[image: Reactive table]

**Scenario 1**

When the global text box value is changed the entire text box inside the table gets changed which is working fine.

**Scenario 2**

When one updates `Average` column value the corresponding row gets updated with the new value.

*In this case update of first row works fine,but when I update second row I'm getting null in the `JSON`*

**Scenario 3**

When I update any text field (not global and average column) I need to generate only the changed value with the corresponding other attributes.

Eg: If I change value of Likes for Canada from 0.0 to 56 I should get only that object like shown below and this change should reflect irrespective of whichever field I update

```
 {
  "family": "FOOD",
  "globalAverageValue": "5.0",
  "country": [
    {
      "name": "Canada",
      "countryAverageValue": "2.0",
      "tastes": [
        {
          "id": "1",
          "name": "Like",
          "value": "56"
        } 
      ]
    }
```

I've used `populateTextDataToJSON` method in which I'm passing all level of inedex but it dosen't see to work.Any suggestions on handling this case?Thanks

Plunker link [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/SgAJ0DWtTwzRQNvXUkYO?p=preview)